# Free energy been a minium confusion?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that if I hold the temperature and volume constant, then the Helmholtz free energy will try and be a minium. Now let us say I am doing a process changing the volume. Let us say at a point (i.e. $(T,p,V)$)we have two possible free energies $F_1$ and $F_2$ (such a situation occurs when looking a phase transitions) then (even though the volume is not constant) can we say that the system will configure itself to give the lowest of the two possible free energies? Either way why?

(I found this question difficult to word so if any part is confusing just let me know)

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the volume then the system is not in thermodynamic equilibrium and so *free energy* becomes ill-defined, see [non-equilibrium thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-equilibrium_thermodynamics).

But even when you're in thermodynamic equilibrium, you're only guaranteed to move to the *local* free energy minimum, not the global. Glass is an example of this: it becomes kinetically trapped in a *meta*stable state.

Comment: What if the process is quasistatic?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification In that case you can approximate the system as being in equilibrium, and the conclusion in my second paragraph remains: it won't *necessarily* move to the global minimum. Another example of this is superheating/supercooling.